# How to prevent destroy data from DataTable with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datatables

I'm try to implement DataTables with Angular, I'm googled and some many solutions is creating directives, its ok but is very old only "normal" way draw a DataTable, the problem is sorting or typing into search box my data is lost!! E.g:

[image: Example]

And my code:

View

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ui.utils']);

myApp.controller("CompanyController", function ($scope, $window, CompanyService) {

    $scope.Companies = [];
    $scope.Company = {};

    $scope.dataTableOpt = {
        //custom datatable options
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, 'All']],
    };
    $scope.$watch("data", function (value) {
        console.log("Data changed, refresh table:");
        var val = value || null;
        if (val) {

        }
    });

    $scope.InitializeIndexView = function () {
                
        var getAllProcess = CompanyService.GetAllCompanies();

        getAllProcess.then(function (response) {
            //console.log(response.data)
            
            $scope.Companies = response.data;
            
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })

    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<table id="company-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" ui-jq="DataTable" ui-options="dataTableOpt">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Register time</th>
                    <th>Short Name</th>
                    <th>Long Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Owner Client</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in Companies">
                    <td>{{item._id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.RegisterTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.LongName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.ShortName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.CompanyStatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.OwnerClient}}</td>
                    <td><a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Company")&CompanyId={{item._id}}">Edit</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","Company")&CompanyId={{item._id}}">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Edit 1:**
I follow these snippet and works fine because data is static: http://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/RRBzda

Comment: uhm, i think it's more easy to use ng-table, it has the features of sorting and searching that you're trying to implement

Answer (score 0):

Angular Js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

$scope.isDisabledupdate = true;

$scope.GetAllData = function () {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:8200/Employee/Get_AllEmployee"
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;
    }, function () {
        alert("Error Occur");
    })
};
$scope.vm = {};
$scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);
```

View Page

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-init="GetAllData()">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" datatable="ng" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>S.no</th>
                            <th>
                                ID
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                City Name
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Actions
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="Emp in employees">
                            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                            <td>
                                {{Emp.CId}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{Emp.CityName}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="getCustomer(Emp)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="deleteemp(Emp)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

I hope this code will help you....

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it tomorrow